# How to create this Android custom "check-box" like selection in a smart way (and for over 100 items)?

Tags: java, android, xml, selection

I am trying to create an item selection logic for this layout. Basically every item acts as a check-box. In theory, the selection idea is pretty simple, you click on an item once - gets selected, click on it again - gets deselected, click on another item - the new one gets selected and the old one gets unselected. Basically you can't select more than one.

What is more important is that every time you check an item, the rounded rectangular background changes from white (invisible) to blue with a ripple effect (I already have this background resource made in XML), then the text color also changes from blue to white to contrast the background and also the resource image for the icon changes to the white counterpart (in the image bellow it doesn't cause I forgot to add it, but the bills icon should be changed to the white PNG counter part).

What I'm looking for is for a smart code with minimal lines that can be used for a list of over 100 different items. Also a better XML layout for such a selection. I initially hardcoded the items in Linear Layouts and I know it's a cheap way that doesn't work with many elements.

[image]

This is the code I wrote for this, I tried adding every text and icons in lists (including their XML IDs) and change them dynamically but I need a way better solution than mine.

```
optionContainers = new LinearLayout[10];
optionTexts = new TextView[10];
optionIcons = new ImageView[10];

drawableBuilderBlue = new int[]{R.drawable.food_blue, R.drawable.flowers_blue, R.drawable.groceries_blue, R.drawable.transport_blue, R.drawable.holiday_blue, R.drawable.bills_blue, R.drawable.clothes_blue, R.drawable.items_blue, R.drawable.pharmacy_blue, R.drawable.others_blue};
drawableBuilder = new int[]{R.drawable.food, R.drawable.flowers, R.drawable.groceries, R.drawable.transport, R.drawable.holiday, R.drawable.bills, R.drawable.clothes, R.drawable.items, R.drawable.pharmacy, R.drawable.others};
idContainers = new String[]{"option_container_1", "option_container_2", "option_container_3", "option_container_4", "option_container_5", "option_container_6", "option_container_7", "option_container_8", "option_container_9", "option_container_10"};
idTexts = new String[]{"option_text_1", "option_text_2", "option_text_3", "option_text_4", "option_text_5", "option_text_6", "option_text_7", "option_text_8", "option_text_9", "option_text_10"};
idIcons = new String[]{"option_icon_1", "option_icon_2", "option_icon_3", "option_icon_4", "option_icon_5", "option_icon_6", "option_icon_7", "option_icon_8", "option_icon_9", "option_icon_10"};
isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;

for (int i = 0; i < idContainers.length; i++) {
    tempC = getResources().getIdentifier(idContainers[i], "id", getPackageName());
    tempT = getResources().getIdentifier(idTexts[i], "id", getPackageName());
    tempI = getResources().getIdentifier(idIcons[i], "id", getPackageName());
    optionContainers[i] = dialog.findViewById(tempC);
    optionTexts[i] = dialog.findViewById(tempT);
    optionIcons[i] = dialog.findViewById(tempI);
    optionContainers[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_selection);
    optionTexts[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ca5c4"));
    optionTexts[i].setTypeface(SR);
    optionIcons[i].setImageResource(drawableBuilderBlue[i]);

    int finalI = i;
    optionContainers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            optionContainers[finalI].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_selection);
            optionTexts[finalI].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            optionIcons[finalI].setImageResource(drawableBuilder[finalI]);
            for(int j = 0; j<finalI; j++)
            {
                optionIcons[j].setImageResource(drawableBuilderBlue[j]);
                optionContainers[j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_selection);
                optionTexts[j].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ca5c4"));
            }
            for(int k=finalI+1; k<idContainers.length; k++)
            {
                optionIcons[k].setImageResource(drawableBuilderBlue[k]);
                optionContainers[k].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_selection);
                optionTexts[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ca5c4"));
            }
            switch (finalI)
            {
                case 0: isFood = true; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 1: isFood = false; isFlowers = true; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 2: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = true; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 3: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = true; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 4: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = true; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 5: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = true; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 6: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = true; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 7: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = true; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 8: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = true; isOthers = false;
                    break;
                case 9: isFood = false; isFlowers = false; isGroceries = false; isTransport = false; isHoliday = false; isBills = false; isClothes = false; isItems = false; isPharmacy = false; isOthers = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Again, even I am aware that the booleans at the bottom of the code are extremely unprofessional and I need a better selection code. Thank you.

Comment: For a start, you could use an array for your booleans. Or have an Enum for the options, and maintain a list of the selected Enums.

Comment: Tried with an array of booleans, for some reason it didn't work. I'll try it once more to see where it goes but concerning the XML layout, should I be trying to use GridView  or is there a better way?

Comment: I am not an Android specialist, I can't answer about the best layout